# How to execute a docker-compose "pre-"down script?

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to execute a shell script upon `docker-compose down` command (which results in removed containers)?
E.g. I want to create a backup consisting of a DB dump and a set of resulting directories, archive them and name with a version and a timestamp. And all that before containers are removed.
Simple persisting data in attached volumes doesn't solve the problem completely as there is no event triggering the aforementioned steps upon `docker-compose down`

Comment: Just trap SIGTERM on the container side

Comment: @KamilCuk That may be problematic to do outside across multiple containers. Say I create a tarball, which snapshots database from one container and multiple directories from other containers and place it in one timestamped tarball